# PDF Blob is not showing content with rest api, Angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to print pdf using blob in angular 6 with rest api, but it is returning blank content print file.

1. http api

   ```js
   printInvoice(invoiceCode: string): Observable<Blob> {
       return this.http.get<Blob>(this.API_DOMAIN + `/api/v1/data/invoice/show?invoiceCodes=${invoiceCode}`, {responseType: 'blob' as 'json'})
   }
   ```
2. Calling http api

```js
printInvoice(invoiceCode: string) {
    this.dataService.printInvoice(invoiceCode).subscribe(response => {
      console.log(response);
      var blob = new Blob([response], { type: "application/pdf" });
      const blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      const iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
      iframe.style.display = "none";
      iframe.src = blobUrl;
      document.body.appendChild(iframe);
      iframe.contentWindow.print();
    });
  }
```

3. Response of API.

%PDF-1.4
%����
5 0 obj
<>stream
x����r�0@���O�������k��yh��ޘ�^`��-�N�>~)>�Ĵǵ���g�xg�����鑏���?"���@bǒ��L�=�rA��V4�Ҿ�Oκ��?ճ�*��2"G��\��(\�9��\?Pqؐ����,jգ�[l�/����P���,���s�uy�U����μW����(�>��w(,a�����T3V��d����B��J!�J�5��֧�^�J���$f�%�[�A�>��Ȭ���D����7��Z[��G&>�څM?r�������K��(eS�����\r��jKC+vm�y��V�]fܚ�[Ж�����;�7��p�#NJUt_�6��Ie��Z�����&.c_]</��w�P� �Ϣ̙�YR?g�Г��U
���O���5ٺ��M�Sܾ��l-X����   [�����h����5�M��e�h��w�Za��'�6wG�
endstream
endobj
6 0 obj
<</ColorSpace/DeviceRGB/Subtype/Image/Height 130/Filter/FlateDecode/Type/XObject/Width 255/SMask 5 0 R/Length 649/BitsPerComponent 8>>stream
x���Kr�0@���>�D�b���x�*�2�6=���E���
���s����?�r�읍�ώ�g���δ��oﳣ����qv>oq���l���?�%L�c�����s�S����j>(�l�;;��oS����aEW��fj��<��ǯT�L�*��9O;?VN:���ܷ�5Y��eM�xbe��ͥ��}��MEF�[����(���7�o����<��^�e�(*�<8D�RI�!�w� Z�[@�(o�����NR� m�IRo�t�$�H�����<
�^z��W�`�~љ�T�����5�MS�[���r�SL��}��դԚ3�X}���ٯ�=�{��p�?������   �l�������u���=�   ���R�
8'��5�̾�G��X3|@��Bv��?ճ�g<5�;�i�֍�T_�(�]���>.%��j}Te�"uj$�?������:kN  �U�������=�����Z�����XK����7�fH٫]2���l��s�!s�IjV�p��g�X�4;cIp����>��ͳ,9�S&��"���]W���
FS�*Yl�p)�Pb
endstream
endobj
7 0 obj
<>stream
x��YYs�8~ׯ��Ni���<�4���֎#[���R�EQ��,%:$����4�"Hv\�����
���j5!Ō��f��%��k37I��ps���5��Q���������K�Kѿ��+�H�  �b"�j7��W�����d�J�F���2�䏫�J�X��FFq��D���Tr���z�L�(�`�Bp2@h5Fk1�����c�������6Cׄ�B9�eD+�A��bv��R�7�R��Q,z$���Y\��ȣ����'����S���q(l�=j�Iw���
�ϳr�Vh^p[�OS&>�h����O��&O���׽آ�r��� .�
�^��&���Ҽ���sZ�r؃����2������!̏wLT��r#g#s��6��?�K�q��8y��M�ȡ--ⵅ㋏YsA1,�@hW����
b�%Z��k�dވ4݈u�3*�0z@9�8�Dlq��Y>�2I����i���!�Aw�C?��D�M�ܹ�PBYm��\�(�{QVMZx���,���s��iO_wrߠ� Z<"�cc�x����x��9�]WyQ�U9�c_��@��G��a�{E�fSɺ�h?�7���*C�1jo`���Y�!�Ż�Eҫ\�r�N�O/�m�Ⱑ��A��>N���Ң��2�B�O��-/97y��6���Uyx޺!�'IO����?� �x�G^����X1��p��B�*�3u2�j�7)bp}�)L1�P���b�B���CdT��f�z�jфG��o�c8�������������I��74q�}�I8l8:M��(�xu,6���|�n�1t; Cw��t��4�o��t���t�����k2t�J�$��;PK�4.��
yu8�K}���u4�/7݄Q�4��:��&/�5*��]YnjOK�H�X]��j��$#,c��C��CeN"��ǅ���4m��oE@�#�t���}㑁���';�t]������Ᏼ8X���"�n�i:�ԕflX������r5ԩ��X=��G�uW��~������J`���Uτ��B���*)�(+��B
��y5r�*JZA�_�8��ڔ~�����I
|Xރ;�Ρ�q��Z�*�t���|����wy͠����T�R    �
ݻ�X"�H"�"���pء3���0�<L�ˈ��6O��݌���'��Q�è{��y�C���װRz�@��0H�)N�ȌO2L1�SPW
JCW�)���b�A�� S5HC�ó��bx�I8ꊡ���%
�F�֋��O�n�1t;��n��t������5H��5H��:��j��>J�$�utPK�4nυ�aIC�2�>�����6��z�B�Ν�eWv=�6&�˲I��/}FA��OU�Cv~2OA���@��Z<��������f��3S�M��ܲbJ���8��������H�>�䔚��:K��ަճTm��=�VV��9>���h���q/ч�v���q5���"e���WV����}�_�y-AE�jc�Zc�iv^�������CT��e��h��y=3_k�`�m�p����}n�=]4���6L?$5]ݵ�\�<�ޮ�W��b4��l�?SG3���~��f5� ��H%? 
(������v��=����*���i����=,4�) ПmZ�D�6m�LJn�H�m���G�YsH�R�ǰ�g�Z�y1}V�P��*k?���ɳX�HRV��T[��ʪ�Y �KР\����a�^��D��rKMz��s�χ*�7y��� ,^[6��/��٪��C׹S�T�Y�%�
c͏h�J�ށ��v5��u���z#7��MY�ԓ!\T/ ��t���q���
N���������_�Q�hQ{�s4��# �����.
�`�P���r���lK�([����)�W��<�8�ZA��n%!�@וg�JS��+8C�*�*�g
t+1�KSb�C���>�}�{���=�
endstream
endobj
9 0 obj
<</Contents 7 0 R/Type/Page/Resources<</ProcSet [/PDF /Text /ImageB /ImageC /ImageI]/Font<</F1 2 0 R/F2 4 0 R>>/XObject<</Xf1 1 0 R/Xf2 3 0 R/img3 6 0 R/img2 5 0 R>>>>/Parent 8 0 R/MediaBox[0 0 595 842]>>
endobj
10 0 obj
<</S/JavaScript/JS(this.print\(\);)>>
endobj
2 0 obj
<</Subtype/Type1/Type/Font/BaseFont/Helvetica/Encoding/WinAnsiEncoding>>
endobj
4 0 obj
<</Subtype/Type1/Type/Font/BaseFont/Helvetica-Bold/Encoding/WinAnsiEncoding>>
endobj
1 0 obj
<</Subtype/Form/Filter/FlateDecode/Type/XObject/Matrix [1 0 0 1 0 0]/FormType 1/Resources<</ProcSet [/PDF /Text /ImageB /ImageC /ImageI]/Font<</F1 2 0 R>>>>/BBox[0 0 239.2 35.66]/Length 361>>stream
x���;n�@D{�bˤQ8� 9�.`�SH���a�x�I'D�#wv,�����/��<��n���.���Ij�4
��oڵ�]˻6JQ��'͍�D`�ɼ1Ztf��#
��]��HR�n�A2��.��Ĺ�tFӕ,�˨�����ȓ�Bu��=H�-��թWO<i/ܫw�%��L&v#X���Ė�
��
ȅ9���H������L&(�J�!H]�-sq���+�aQx���S�D�Q�*�4��&���i��O�J̼^7�3����n4�C���a:�kr�.��]��]d�Gm9�G��-)�/�2�/��'B�e¦[@�U۵}  �����u��X��S^������5},�/#�d�
endstream
endobj
3 0 obj
<</Subtype/Form/Filter/FlateDecode/Type/XObject/Matrix [1 0 0 1 0 0]/FormType 1/Resources<</ProcSet [/PDF /Text /ImageB /ImageC /ImageI]/Font<</F1 2 0 R>>>>/BBox[0 0 142.4 35.66]/Length 268>>stream
x��S�ND1�����I��+�����
H,���;�U=�da�\ױ��bO�I#k����
��v(o�?�zw�ڄ4_.��V��x�1M�;#��`��xgI�>�KI||'j��O��M��6i�3�R+lS�ji6�bꭷZl
u&Q��U�z�̡vۧF�����$�dg�����ڐXo �%�:���d�k?���h�5��a���Հ�=��q@�y ;�y��A��4��b�����T���wx@)�����FD���Wx�!�/
endstream
endobj
8 0 obj
<>
endobj
11 0 obj
<>
endobj
12 0 obj
<>
endobj
13 0 obj
<>>>
endobj
14 0 obj
<>
endobj
xref
0 15
0000000000 65535 f 
0000004063 00000 n 
0000003882 00000 n 
0000004648 00000 n 
0000003970 00000 n 
0000000015 00000 n 
0000000666 00000 n 
0000001482 00000 n 
0000005140 00000 n 
0000003608 00000 n 
0000003828 00000 n 
0000005191 00000 n 
0000005245 00000 n 
0000005284 00000 n 
0000005377 00000 n 
trailer
<<3a3bfb9a3366db478c7bf413ede5ba2e>]/Root 13 0 R/Size 15>>
%iText-5.4.2
startxref
5531
%%EOF

Comment: Does it matter that invoiceCode is a string and you are trying to return blob as json?

Comment: Instead of `iframe.style.display = "none";` try `iframe.style.visibility = "hidden";`. Although, why do you want to hide it?

Comment: It has been solved. Same code is working fine. PDF file was corrupted.